# SQL Server Query to get Data from a Table where each row is a Table

Tags: sql-server, join, datatables, system, common-table-expression

I have a schema where I have multiple tables some with time and some without it. So I created a query where I have listed 3 tables say which has time like this :

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT   
        CONCAT(schema_name(t.schema_id), '.', t.name) AS table_name,
        c.name AS 'time'
    FROM
        sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE
        schema_name(t.schema_id) = 'Prod'
        AND c.name = 'mytime'
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Now my output looks like ( I am showing 3 rows for the example):

Table O

```
table_name        time
--------------------------
Prod.tableA       mytime
Prod.tableB       mytime
Prod.tableC       mytime
```

So usually what I want is to get the max(mytime) from each Table/Schema combination . So for a single table I can do

```
SELECT MAX(mytime) 
FROM Prod.tableA
```

However in this case I want to generate this from table O for each table and my output should look like:

Table F

```
table_name      mymax(time) 
--------------------------------------------
Prod.tableA     max(mytime) from Prod.tableA
Prod.tableB     max(mytime) from Prod.tableA
Prod.tableC     max(mytime) from Prod.tableA
```

How to achieve this using another select/variable declaration etc? Any help or ideas will be extremely appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Can this help? You still have a bit of work, check if the output is what you like and then uncomment the exec.

```
DECLARE @SchemaName NVARCHAR(100) = 'foo',
@ColumnName NVARCHAR(100) = 'bar',
@sql NVARCHAR(max)

    SELECT @SchemaName + '.'+  t.name AS [Schema.Table],'( SELECT MAX(' + @ColumnName + ') FROM ['+ @SchemaName +'].['+t.name+']) ' AS MaxValue
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE s.name = @SchemaName
-------
SELECT @sql = 
    STUFF((
    SELECT 'UNION ALL ' + 'SELECT ' + '''' + '[' + ISNULL(@SchemaName,'') + '].['+  t.name + ']' + '''' + ' AS [Schema.Table] ,( SELECT MAX(' + @ColumnName + ') FROM ['+ @SchemaName +'].['+t.name+']) AS Max' + @ColumnName + ' '
    FROM sys.tables t
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    WHERE s.name = @SchemaName
    for xml path('')
),1,10,'') 

PRINT @sql
    
--EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Thank you @LoBai. Will check and keep you posted how it goes.

Comment: I checked the script and its doig something when I am printing the Table and its giving:

Comment: I checked the script and its doig something when I am printing the Table and its giving something like this   ColA                     ColB                                                                                                                                              
                             ProdA.tableA         Select max(time) from ProdA.tableA          etc                           Executing gives syntax error.